# howto emulate 2-sample t-test in scipy

Tags: python, math, statistics, scipy, excel-formula

I'm trying to emulate MS Excel's t-probe function in Python. I need to do this because I have to automate some calculations there were previously done in Excel. Here is my test program:

```
import scipy.stats
a = [5, 0.9,  -0.4, -0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0, -0.8]
b = [1.1, 0.9, -0.5, -0.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, -0.1, -0.7]

print scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a,b, equal_var=True)
```

This is the result:

```
(array(0.6661542796363409), 0.51376033318001801)
```

However, Excel gives this value for the same input: 0.35844407

I noticed that they have used tail=2 parameter (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ttest-HP005209325.aspx ). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to calculate two tailed t-test with scipy. (In fact I don't know what it is.)

Another very strange thing is that in scipy, I get a sightly different result when I change the order of samples. E.g. if I move -0.7 to the head of b, then I get  0.51376033318001824 instead of 0.51376033318001801. Not a big difference, but still.

For Excel, it is a whole new story - looks like the two tailed t-test gives a significantly different result when the order of samples is different.

The question is: how can I emulate Excel's version of two tailed t-test in scipy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `Excel` is computing `ttest_rel`:

```
In [15]: import scipy.stats as stats

In [20]: stats.ttest_rel(a, b)
Out[20]: (array(0.9677712267394081), 0.35844406902161985)
```

Use `stats.ttest_rel` when `a` and `b` are related. [The docs](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/scipy/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) say:

> Examples for the use [of ttest_rel] are scores of the same set of student in
>   different exams, or repeated sampling from the same units.

Use [stats.ttest_ind](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/scipy/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) when `a` and `b` are independent.

> We can use [ttest_ind], if we observe two independent samples from the
>   same or different population, e.g. exam scores of boys and girls or of
>   two ethnic groups.

Comment: One more thing I don't understand. In the Python version, the order of samples doesn't count. E.g. if I call `a.sort(),b.sort()` then the return value of ´ttest_rel` is the same. However, if I do it in Excel (sort the values) then I get a totally different result. Why is that? (I know this is not a real programming question anymore)

Comment: The order does matter, even for `ttest_rel`. For example, `ttest_rel(a, sorted(b))` gives a different result than `ttest_rel(a, b)`. It is a coincidence that `ttest_rel(sorted(a), sorted(b))` gives the same result as `ttest_rel(a, b)`. In the source code for `ttest_rel` there is a line, `d = (a - b).astype(np.float64)`, so it is pretty clear that order does matter. Now, if you are feeding the exact same data to Excel and `ttest_rel` and getting different results, then its back to the drawing board...

Comment: Thanks. So it was by accident. :-) I noticed however, that for ttest_ind, the order does not matter. But I can understand that.

Comment: in this case(`stats.ttest_rel(a, b)`) what is the meaning of a small p-value here ?